# In MySQL, why is a non-ASCII character really two characters?

Tags: mysql, regex, utf-8

I have a MySQL database with default encoding set to utf8. So it should be no problem to work with characters that are non-ASCII. But it seems to be a bit more difficult when it comes to regular expressions via the REGEXP command.

I'm trying to query records based on regular expressions using wildcards. The functions MySQL offers are sufficient for me but they seem slightly broken in that a non-ASCII character (I've tried § and °) isn't matched by one wildcard but by two.

For example, if I search for a wiki page named '§123' which is in the database then

```
SELECT * FROM wikipages WHERE title REGEXP '^.123$'
```

would not return anything, but

```
SELECT * FROM wikipages WHERE title REGEXP '^..123$'
```

returns the desired page (notice the additional wildcard symbol).

For ASCII characters only one wildcard symbol is needed. I suppose that has something to do with how many bytes are used to encode the character in utf8. However, I find this behavior rather ugly since I cannot work with regular expressions if MySQL doesn't treat all the characters equally.

Is there actually a good reason why it doesn't work as suspected? And does anyone has any idea how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this simple example, `WHERE title LIKE '_123'` would work, though in more general examples you'd lose the power of REGEXP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Warning**
>
> The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

UTF-8 is a potentially multi-byte character set. Basically, trying to do wildcard matches in REGEXPs against UTF-8 characters is going to fail sometimes.

You could either search for the specific character (which would automatically be expanded to the right number of bytes), or you could use a non-regexp pattern match (e.g. `LIKE`), for things like prefix/postfix searches.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I did not want to use `LIKE` since I'm working with Django which has no wrapper function for this which means I have to take care of character escaping myself. But that seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: @j0ker Have a look at [contains lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-contains). It also [escapes % and _](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#escaping-percent-signs-and-underscores-in-like-statements).

Comment: @cbuckley I thought about `contains()` too, but instead of `LIKE %someword%` I need a query containing `LIKE some_word` since I must be able to exactly specify how the word looks like without the special chars. `contains()` cannot help me with that. I found a blog post dealing with `LIKE` in Django: http://www.yaco.es/blog/en/contribuciones/2012/02/a-simple-and-impossible-query-in-django/

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate the occurrency of wildcard

Try

```
SELECT "§123" REGEXP "^.*123$" - any character 0 - n
SELECT "§123" REGEXP "^.{0,2}123$" - any character 0 - 2
```

Both expressions result in 1. Furthermore MySQL Manual warns about multibyte characters.

Warning
The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Comment: That would work. But I think it's a little unpractical since `'^.{0,2}123$'` would not only match something like `§123` but also `ab123`. I want the query to put exactly one character in there, no more or less, so I guess `LIKE` is the best choice.